# POST Facebook Notification using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post notification using facebook graph api post method but I'm getting

```
(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.
```

However the access_token which I'm sending in querystring is app access token which is fetched using this method

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".FB_APP_ID."&client_secret=".FB_SECRET."&grant_type=client_credentials";
```

I 've seen few guys have implemented it but don't know why its not working for me, someone pls tell me where I'm wrong in it.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I got it working, here is the change

This line of code will never work, because the internal access_token will override the app access_token which we are trying to pass in query string.

```
$this->facebook->api("/".$to_userId."/notifications?access_token=$app_token_url&template=message",'POST');
```

So Use this code

```
    $data = array(
    'href'=> 'https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/',
    'access_token'=> $app_token,
    'template'=> 'test'
    );
    try {

    $this->facebook->api("/".$to_userId."/notifications",'POST',$data);
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

    }
```

Comment: Use our graph api explorer tool to see what is being returned with your URL https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Yes I've used that, I'm getting same thing  {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 15
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Is your app accidentally configured as a 'native/desktop' app in the app settings? if so, change it back to 'web'

Comment: is your client secret (in advanced settings) the same as your app secret? if so, change it - if it's the same as your app secret and your app was ever set to native/desktop it needs to be changed before it'll work - if that doesn't do it, it's likely you actually aren't using an App Access Token, though you said you were, so i'm not sure what else it could be